# How to extract only a string using jsonpath in Zabbix?

Tags: json, jsonpath, zabbix

I have:

```
  {
    "pid": 3922,
    "ppid": 1,
    "name": "tnslsnr",
    "cmdline": "/u01/app/19.0.0/grid/bin/tnslsnr TEST_HOM -no_crs_notify -inherit",
    "user": "grid",
    "group": "oinstall",
    "uid": 54322,
    "gid": 54321,
    "vsize": 143036416,
    "pmem": 0.405007,
    "rss": 23068672,
    "data": 3624960,
    "exe": 856064,
    "hwm": 23240704,
    "lck": 0,
    "lib": 92299264,
    "peak": 143040512,
    "pin": 0,
    "pte": 204800,
    "size": 4616192,
    "stk": 135168,
    "swap": 0,
    "cputime_user": 0.030000,
    "cputime_system": 0.020000,
    "state": "sleeping",
    "ctx_switches": 359,
    "threads": 1,
    "page_faults": 1
  }
```

Then I use `$..cmdline` to return only `cmdline`

```
/u01/app/19.0.0/grid/bin/tnslsnr TEST_HOM -no_crs_notify -inherit
```

But how Can I return the string after "tnslsnr", in this case "TEST_HOM"? But sometime it can be other name than TEST_HOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second preprocessing rule, for example a regular expression `.*tnslsnr ([^ ]*)` :

[image]